# How to generalize result on positive matrices from inverses to pseudoinverses?

Tags: pseudoinverse, positive-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive (but not strictly positive) matrices. $B^{+}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $B$ and $X^{*}$ denotes the transpose of $X$.

I'm trying to show that $A \geq XB^{+}X^*$ is equivalent to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & X\\
X^* & B
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0,
$$

What I tried doing was using matrix similarity
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & X\\
X^* & B
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
I & -XB^{+}\\
O & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & X\\
X^* & B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & O\\
-B^{+}X^* & I
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but the RHS is

\begin{bmatrix}
A-XB^{+}X^{*} & X(I-B^{+}B)\\
(I-BB^{+})X^* & B
\end{bmatrix}

If $(I-BB^{+})X^*$ and $X(I-B^{+}B)$ vanished, then I'd be done since then I could look at the upper-left corner with $A-XB^{+}X^*$ and see it must be nonnegative.

But since I'm dealing with pseudoinverses, how do I show this will still be the case even if
$(I-BB^{+})X$ and $X(I-B^{+}B)$ don't vanish?